# Specify HTTPS for custom WCF Binding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight

I have an custom binding defined as follows:

```
<customBinding>
<binding name="binaryHttpBinding">
 <binaryMessageEncoding />
 <httpTransport />
</binding>
```

This is used for an endpoint that a Silverlight 3 application uses to connect to the service.  This works fine under HTTP, but i would like to specify this binding to use HTTPS and I am kinda lost on how to define that.  I am using selfSSL.exe from the IIS Resource Toolkit to setup an SSL on my local machine.  I can browse the svc file fine through HTTPS (although the browser throws up a warning that its not a recognized cert).  How can i setup this custom binding to use transport security over HTTPS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple change, use the httpsTransport like so:

```
<customBinding>
<binding name="binaryHttpBinding">
 <binaryMessageEncoding />
 <httpsTransport />
</binding>
```

Comment: ok, do you know how many times, and how long i read over the MSDN section of httpsTransport and completely read right over the 's' part and kept reading httpTransport?

Comment: its just one char, don't beat yourself up :)