# WCF Custom Binding or basichttpbinding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I am trying to implement WCF client. The server requires WSSE header.

I am able to make it work with HTTP. However it doesn't work with HTTPS.

I have been given 2 URLs for test, one with HTTPS and one with HTTP. The production server will be using HTTPS.

I am using CustomBinding to make it work with HTTP

Here is the code for binding:

```
var securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
securityElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
securityElement.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;
var encodingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);
var transportElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
var binding = new CustomBinding(securityElement, encodingElement, transportElement);
return binding;
```

It works well when I use HTTP URL. When I try HTTPS with the same binding, I am getting this error:

"The 'CustomBinding'.'http://tempuri.org/' binding for the 'serviceRequestUpdate_PortType'.'http://schemas.officedepot.com/ODTechServices/serviceRequestUpdate' contract is configured with an authentication mode that requires transport level integrity and confidentiality. However the transport cannot provide integrity and confidentiality."

I have also tried using basichttpbinding for HTTPS as below:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
return binding;
```

Now in this case I am getting below error:

"Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security."

I noticed the actual web service call is made and operation is performed. It seems it has issues in receiving the response. I have also noticed that when I make a request, I am passing time stamps but the response does not have time stamps with it which makes the difference in binding mismatch probably. But there is no way to set `IncludeTimestamp = false` if I use `basicHttpBinding`.

Comment: I got my answer

Just needed to change

var transportElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();

to

var transportElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();

And use custom binding.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because user got his anwser

Comment: @Ravi - Getting an answer makes a question off topic?

Comment: @Tim Nope. but user already got his answer. so. if needed can reopen the close votes :) no issues

Comment: Maybe the OP should answer his own question rather than comment on it.

Comment: That 's' in Https is rather important.

Comment: The OP was setting up the binding programmatically, but here is a similar solution to someone who was setting the binding through a configuration file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420899/specify-https-for-custom-wcf-binding?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my answer Just needed to change var transportElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement(); to var transportElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement(); And use custom binding

Comment: You can also mark this an an answer so people will know it worked for you.

Comment: What a PITA debugging this one was for me.. thanks for the CUSTOM binding to allow EnableUnsecuredResponse setting...